# Four fair dice are rolled, we count (6,6,6,5) and not (6,6,5,6), why ? And when two dice are thrown simultaneously we count (5,6) and (6,5) both, why?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, dice

Four fair dice are rolled, we count (6,6,6,5) and not (6,6,5,6), why ? And when two dice are thrown simultaneously we count (5,6) and (6,5) both, why? Is it because we throw simultaneously or there is something else ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Probably some specifics of the problem that you neglected to read, and consequently write in your post. Of course, people here can't know what hasn't been written.

Comment: Something else, you did not give information what is it exactly.

Comment: Seems like the simplest way to close a poor question is to declare it duplicate of another  question., preferably also poor. Real duplication is not needed.